# final boolean [] vs final boolean inside Runnable

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

Why is the following allowed:

```
final boolean [] success = new boolean[1];
    Thread httpThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            HTTPConnect httpConnect = new HTTPConnect(getContext());
            success[0] = false
            ...
            if (whatever)
            success[0] = true;
```

But the following is not?

```
final boolean success;
    Thread httpThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            HTTPConnect httpConnect = new HTTPConnect(getContext());
            success = false
            ...
            if (whatever)
            success = true;
```

I am referring to the `boolean success` here.
At first I thought it was because a local declaration would lose scope, while a declaration on heap would survive after scope ends, but this doesn't seem to be the case as a declaration like `final ArrayList<Foo> bar = new ArrayList<>()` can't be assigned a value.

Comment: Removing all unnecessary parts from your code, you ask why this doesn't work:
  
    `boolean success;
    success[0] = true;`

Answer is simple: because `success` is a primitive boolean value not an array.

Comment: @Kiryl It was a typo, fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are actually wrapping the `boolean` value inside an array so that you can change the content of the array but you are not changing the reference of the variable `success` itself.

The same result could be obtained by using an `AtomicBoolean` (or `AtomicReference` in general).

The problem of variables modified in anonymous inner classes arises in the following scenario

```
boolean success;
Thread httpThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    success = false;
    ....
```

This is not allowed because you are *changing* what `success` is referring to. If you use a `boolean[]`, then you are not changing what is `success` referring to but a value contained inside the object referred, so there are no problems.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your second example has a couple of typos: since `success` is a `boolean`, the assignment statements should not be subscripted.

I'm assuming that in both cases, `success` is a local variable. If it is a field, then you can simply eliminate the `final` and the second case will work (after eliminating the subscripts).

The reason the second approach won't work for a local variable is that you cannot assign to a `final` variable after it has been assigned. The story is a bit different for an array: you still can't assign a new array to `success`, but you can assign new values to elements of the array. That's why the first approach works. Using an array like this is a common idiom for dealing with both this problem and with the problem that Java methods don't have "out" arguments.